# How to determine bounds or number of iterations in Binary Search?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

While implementing Binary Search, We have two ways of deciding when to terminate: terminate when the search space gets smaller than some predetermined bound or do a fixed number of iterations. So my question is basically, how to determine these bounds or the number of iterations after we can terminate our algorithm. Is there any predefined algorithm or process for it?

Comment: The 'bounds' are usually set by `while (lower < upper)`, ending with a width of 1 (found) or empty/zero (not found).

Comment: @HenkHolterman In case of implementing Binary Search on set of dense real numbers, the exact target value can not be find easily so we can not use (lower<upper) criteria in that case.

Comment: Binary Search is usually associated with discrete sorted arrays. If you are thinking about some sort of optimization (hill climbing) method, better be clear about that and check your terminology. A link to some source would be nice.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Actually I am trying to approximate the values of monotonic functions with less error possible using Binary Search, in which domain of the function is the set of real numbers.

Comment: You should give a complete descriptions of your problem, we can't guesse the bounts if the problem is not clear. Less error than what>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine the kind of binary search you are performing maybe on some double value. So you need to be as accurate as possible with some limitation on number of iteration.

With ith iteration in binary search you are left with a sample space of at most (high-low) / 2^i big.

Now depending on how close you want this value to be you have to set the value of i.

**For example**:

```
high = 100000
low = 0
```

After 30th iteration the sample space left you will be as small as `0.00009313225`

Which means for this range, in worst case after 30th iteration the exact position will be `0.00009313225` distance away.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say your function is some monotonic function `f(i).` 
I think there is no catch all strategy this really depends on the problem or function.

But the a way we could ty to find a bound is by just checking the following:

```
while(f(i)< user defined statement):
    i*=a     (a= 2,3,4,5)   depending on your problem
```

So that the `i` you find is your upperbound, and you could say that your lower bound is `i/2`.

Your `user defined statement` will probably have something with this error you mention. But you should really clarify your problem!